# Getting application name from process name

Tags: android

I have a file that store list of running processes in android phones. I want to find out the name of the applications associated with that process. Is there any convenient way to find out this. I could have saved the application name while saving the name of the processes. Unfortunately I did not do so and now I need to find it out. can anyone please help me regarding this.

thanks
kaisar

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to keep track of a process is find out the PID of the process and from there try to figure out the package name of the application. Specifically I think this is all public information in the OS, however data associated unless otherwise specified is private.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the **process Id** & by using it you can get other information. For detail please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8543401/265167).